# Pros and Cons of Redirecting with HTTP Referer?

Tags: http, flask, keycloak, http-referer

I am currently working on a simgle Flask application with React as front end. I want to have an elegant way to redirect user to their previous page after they complete the log in process. After some research I figured out using HTTP Referer attribute can work very well like below.

```
from flask import request

## Massive other code omitted

@app.route(""/login")
def log_in():
    return redirect(request.referer)
```

I am aware that the referer header is added by the browser. The question is, is this a good practice to redirect user back to where they come from using HTTP referer? Any hidden concern of using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function that returns a good and secure url for redirect and use it in your login view.

```
def safe_redirect_url():
    next_url = request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or url_for("index")
    if next_url and url_parse(next_url).netloc == "":
        return next_url
    return None
```

before you redirect, you can add a check like:

```
 url = safe_redirect_url()
 if url:
     redirect(url)
 else:
     return "Error"
```